# Why does YouTube audo keep playing after closing?

Tags: audio, youtube

[On this page,](http://www.pestpac.com/tour/marketing) if you click any "Watch Video" button, it opens a video. If you hit play and then hit Close, the audio keeps playing. Googling makes it seem like it's just something Google needs to fix, but curious if anyone knew of any way to stop it

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#hp-video").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $("#hp-video iframe").attr("src", $("#hp-video iframe").attr("src"));
});
});
```

That did the trick (with the proper ID of course)

Answer (score 0):

this happens alot to me and i soon found out how to do it.
just turn off the autoplay and turn off the audio of youtube.
and it wont autoplay the next vid and there is no audio on the vid

Comment: Hello @Davis. Your answer seems to answer some other question. Can you review it please? The original question is from year 2016 and the page seems radically redesigned since then.